# What's the preferred vertex data format for OpenGL ES on iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, vertexdata

In the book "Mobile 3D Graphics with OpenGL ES and M3G" the authors say that choosing the correct vertex data format will have huge impact on performance. They recommend GL_SHORT for most vertex data. Does this also apply for iPhone OS?

Answer (score 2):

all of the example code I've seen uses GL_FLOAT; in general with 3D stuff you're doing enough math that integer formats aren't very convenient.

Apple's [OpenGLES Performance Tech Note](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2230.html) recommends using floating point.

They also talk about how to order your per-vertex data for best performance; Jeff LaMarche has an excellent [article](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-8.html) about how to do that.